# Could someone please show me how to create a CGPattern that I can use to stroke a path with an image?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, cgcontext

I want to stroke a path using a .png that I have but I just don't know hot to make a CGPatternRef.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the relevant chapter of the Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_patterns/dq_patterns.html) and [the reference documentation for CGPattern](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1666292-cgpattern).

The essential detail that's buried in the Programming Guide under pages and pages of “LOOK PRETTY PATTERNS” is that you need to write a callback function that draws one instance of the pattern, and pass the pointer to that callback to `CGPatternCreate`. When you draw the pattern, Quartz will call your callback, then tile whatever you drew.

Answer (score 6):

here's a little snippet

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self patternMake2:rect context:context];
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
//      patternMake2
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
void pattern2Callback (void *info, CGContextRef context) {      
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBarBg.png"];
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44), imageRef);
}


- (void)patternMake2:(CGRect)rect context:(CGContextRef)context
{
    static const CGPatternCallbacks callbacks = { 0, &pattern2Callback, NULL };
    //NSLog(@"rect: %f %f %f %f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.x, rect.size.width, rect.size.height); 
    //CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGColorSpaceRef patternSpace = CGColorSpaceCreatePattern(NULL);
    CGContextSetFillColorSpace(context, patternSpace);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(patternSpace);
    CGSize patternSize = CGSizeMake(315, 44);
    CGPatternRef pattern = CGPatternCreate(NULL, self.bounds, CGAffineTransformIdentity, patternSize.width, patternSize.height, kCGPatternTilingConstantSpacing, true, &callbacks);
    CGFloat alpha = 1;
    CGContextSetFillPattern(context, pattern, &alpha);
    CGPatternRelease(pattern);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);       
    //CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Comment: Should we always pass NULL to info?